# Get messages from queue using RabbitMQ.Client

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ.Client for .NET (https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html).

One issue I'm having is how to get all messages content from a queue.

The catch here is that I don't want to consume these messages, I want only to list them.

All methods listed in the docs (BasicConsume, BasicGet) consume the message and then flush them from the queue, which is not what I want.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Which rest api call you mean exactly?

Comment: @Evk my fault. I thought that it was working on the REST API but messages are being consumed too...

Comment: Yes, there is no api to do that, because you should never do that, or even need that - it's against design and goal of rabbitmq. You can dequeue and then requeue or dequeue and then not ack, but it's not the same. So question is why do you need that in first place?

Comment: @Evk I'm developing an admin dashboard where you will be able to see which messages are in the queue to be consumed in several workers.

Comment: Then I think you have to use one of the methods above (requeue or negative ack), but note that it will affect your workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot browse the messages as a database.

The only way is consuming the messages using `autoack = false` and then re-queue the messages.

RabbitMQ is not a database and in general, you should not browse the messages. Browse the message is not a best-practice when you re-queue a message the flag `redelivered` is set to `true`, and maybe you need it for your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
   **Here is the solution for you.**

   1.  **Connect with rabbitMQ using API**  

       public WebClient GetRabbitMqConnection(string userName, string password)
       {
            var client = new WebClient(); 
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            return client;
       }

   2. **Retrieve message by providing appropriate parameter in below method.**

      public string GetRabbitMQMessages(string domainName, string port, string 
                                        queueName, string virtualHost, WebClient 
                                        client, string methodType)
      {
                 string messageResult = string.Empty;
                 string strUri = "http://" + domainName + ":" + port + "/api/queues/" 
                                 + virtualHost + "/";
                 var data = client.DownloadString(strUri + queueName + "/");
                 var queueInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueInfo>(data);
                 if (queueInfo == null || queueInfo.messages == 0)
                     return string.Empty;
                 if (methodType == "POST")
                 {
                     string postbody = "  
                 {\"ackmode\":\"ack_requeue_true\",\"count\":
                  \"$totalMessageCount\",
                  \"name\":\"${DomainName}\",\"requeue\":\"false\",
                  \"encoding\":\"auto\",\"vhost\" : \"${QueueName}\"}";
                  postbody = postbody.Replace("$totalMessageCount", 
                  queueInfo.messages.ToString()).Replace("${DomainName}", 
                  domainName).Replace("${QueueName}", queueName);
                  messageResult = client.UploadString(strUri + queueName + "/get", 
                  "POST", postbody);
                 }
                return messageResult;
        }

    **I wish it will solve your problem. All the best and cheers !!!!!!**
```